# Rest API is not working in Reactjs

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot

I am trying to consume rest api in ReactJS. But it's showing undefined.
Here is my code..

**ReactJS code:**

```
<script type="text/jsx">
            var JavaEEWSTest = React.createClass({
                getInitialState: function () {
                    return {text: ''};
                },
                componentDidMount: function(){

                     $.ajax({
                           url: "http://localhost:8080/hi"
                           }).then(function(data) {

                           this.setState({text: data.text});
                           alert(data.text);
                    }.bind(this))
                 },
                 render: function() {
                     return <div>Response - {this.state.text}</div>;
                 }
             });

            React.render(<JavaEEWSTest />, document.getElementById('component'));

        </script>
```

**Here is my Spring boot code:**

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hi",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "hello";
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 4):

While making AJAX calls, we can use axios-react, the quick link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

And instead of the **function** keyword in your code, you may use the ES6 version's **=>**.

Below is an example of getting the response from the rest API.

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data : []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(URL)
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({data:res.data});
      console.log(this.state.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```